# Analyzing discrete Proportional Data with different sample sizes in GLMM?

Tags: mixed-model, proportion, glmm, sas

I am reaching out to seek guidance regarding an issue that has been troubling me for a while.

In my study, I had participants choose a strategy for expressing 6 different emotions across * 5 social media platforms. This was done by selecting one option from a list of seven strategies, making it a nominal variable.
I then coded the strategies chosen across the 5x6 = 30 different scenarios and computed the **proportion** for each strategy in each scenario. (For example, if 25% of the responses for 'emotion1' chose 'strategy A', it indicates that 'strategy A' was the preferred choice in 25% of the responses when expressing 'emotion1'.)

**The main objectives of my analysis are:**

1To ascertain if there is a variation in the proportion of a particular strategy used across different emotions and social media platforms.
2To determine the relationship between the proportion of a strategy used and the frequency and habits of social media usage.

**Some key characteristics of my data are:**

1Not all participants have used all five social media platforms. Hence, I retained data only for the platforms participants have used. This resulting in varying sample sizes across different platforms.
2the response variable "proportion" is discrete and not normally distributed (from 0~1).

Currently,  I am using SAS for analysis.
Here is what I am doing right now.

1.In the first step, I transformed the data into a long format resembling: (ID strategy emotion1proportion emotion2proportion ...).
I then used a GLMM model with a binomial distribution, a logit link function, and multiple comparisons (LSMEANS) to explore how the 'emotion1proportion' is influenced by the strategy. However, I encountered an error saying "Estimated G matrix is not positive definite" when using the random statement.

2In the second step, I converted the data into a wide format:
ID situation strategyAproportion strategyBproportion ...
positive_sns1
positive_sns2
Using the GLMM model (binomial distribution, logit link function, multiple comparisons: LSMEANS), I investigated how 'strategyAproportion' varies across different emotion categories and its influence by different platforms.

3.In the third step, I employed the GLMM model to examine the relationship between 'strategyAproportion' in various contexts and factors such as social media usage frequency, usage habits, gender, and age.

I am unsure if using the GLMM model is appropriate in this context. Furthermore, it seems the response variable in my model might not strictly follow a binomial distribution since its variance is larger than its mean, raising concerns about the appropriateness of the binomial distribution.
I have also tried using a Poisson distribution, which yielded a smaller AIC. I have uploaded the distribution chart of a specific strategy as shown below.
[image]
I would be profoundly grateful for any suggestions or alternative statistical methodologies you could recommend. Thank you!